# SOA Resource Discovery vs. Service Discovery

Tags: web-services, jboss, soa, uddi

I've been looking into the SOA offerings of jBoss, Oracle, WSO2, etc.., and comparing everything SOA from ESB, application servers, middleware, BPM, goverance and discovery. I thought I had a pretty clear understanding of Service Discovery and UDDI, but in the JBoss docs it mentions "Resource Discovery"..

http://www.jboss.com/pdf/JON_2.3_datasheet.pdf reads: "With JBoss ON, you can auto-discover application resources such as operating systems, applications, and services."

Is this standard SOA stuff beyond **"service discovery"** that most SOA suites offer, or it this something specific to jBoss?, or is "resource discovery" another nomenclature for "service discovery"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss is many things; JBoss ON (Operations Network) specifically is RedHat's supported version of "jopr", an open sourced monitoring and operational tool.

In the context of JON, resources are things that you're monitoring or controlling.  I don't think it's relevant to SOA concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to comparing the discovery features, I recommend you determine whether these features will be useful to you at all. In particular, I think that load balancers cover most discovery scenarios in practice, and are a simpler technology.